# rails belongs_to with select_tag

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, select, belongs-to, html-select

I havle belongs_to association model 'Timetableap' with model 'Aircompany'

```
     class Timetableap < ActiveRecord::Base
        belongs_to :aircompany
      ...
     end


  class Aircompany < ActiveRecord::Base
     has_many :timetableaps
     ...
   end
```

In 'Timetableaps' controller:

```
  class TimetableapsController < ApplicationController
   ...
   def index
     @t = Timetableap.search(params[:search_ap],params[:search_al])
   ...
   end
```

My structure tables
"aircompanies" table

> ```
>   create_table "aircompanies", :force => true do |t|
>      t.string   "iata_code",        :null => false
>      t.string   "icao_code",        :null => false
>      t.string   "awb_prefix"
>      t.string   "airline_name",     :null => false
>      t.integer  "airport_id",       :null => false
>      t.string   "country"
>      t.string   "ap_hubs"
>      t.date     "start"
>      t.date     "end"
>      t.datetime "created_at",       :null => false
>      t.datetime "updated_at",       :null => false
>    end
> ```

"timetableaps" table

> ```
>   create_table "timetableaps", :force => true do |t|
>      t.integer  "Flight_Number"
>      t.integer  "aircompany_id"
>      t.integer  "way_start"
>      t.integer  "way_end"
>      t.string   "TermStart"
>      t.string   "GateStart"
>      t.string   "TermEnd"
>      t.string   "GateEnd"
>      t.string   "TypeOfPlane"
>      t.time     "TimeStart"
>      t.time     "TimeEnd"
>      t.date     "DateOfStartNav"
>      t.date     "DateOfEndNav"
>      t.integer  "s1"
>      t.integer  "s2"
>      t.integer  "s3"
>      t.integer  "s4"
>      t.integer  "s5"
>      t.integer  "s6"
>      t.integer  "s0"
>      t.integer  "e1"
>      t.integer  "e2"
>      t.integer  "e3"
>      t.integer  "e4"
>      t.integer  "e5"
>      t.integer  "e6"
>      t.integer  "e0"
>      t.datetime "created_at",     :null => false
>      t.datetime "updated_at",     :null => false
>    end
> ```

How can I display drop-down list in views with 'aircompany.airline_name'?

```
 <%= select_tag "search_al", options_from_collection_for_select(@t.group("aircompany_id"),"aircompany_id", **"aircompany"**), prompt: "All Airlines" %>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not clear if you want a drop down with all airlines or if they are supposed to be filtered in some way.

If you want all airlines, this works:

```
<%= select_tag "search_al", options_from_collection_for_select(Aircompany.all, :id, :airline_name), prompt: "All Airlines" %>
```

Since `@t` appears to be a collection of `Timetableap` records, you could chose to only display airlines found in the current collection of timetableaps:

```
<%= select_tag "search_al", options_from_collection_for_select(@t.map(&:aircompany).uniq, :id, :airline_name), prompt: "All Airlines" %>
```

Comment: Its not a hash, its an array. If you wanted it sorted by `Aircompany#airline_name` this would work: `@t.map(&:aircompany).uniq.sort_by(&:airline_name)`